# Golf me some cash from the ATM

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

The task is simple. Get me some `1000`, `500` and `100` notes.

How ? you might ask. Don't worry, no need of robbing a bank as there is an ATM nearby which accepts your credit card. But your credit limit is just enough for the task so you have to be careful with the withdrawals.

**Challenge**

Given the number of `1000`, `500` and `100` notes required, calculate the specific withdrawals needed to get at least those many notes. In each withdrawal, the ATM can spit out each of the note based on the following rules:

- Amount withdrawn (`A`) is less than `5000`

  - If `A%1000 == 0`, then ATM spits 1 `500` note, 5 `100` notes and rest `1000` notes
  - Else if `A%500 == 0`, the ATM spits 5 `100` notes, rest `1000` notes
  - Else if `A%1000 < 500`, the ATM spits `floor(A/1000)` `1000` notes and rest `100` notes
  - Else if `A%1000 > 500`, the ATM spits `floor(A/1000)` `1000` notes, 1 `500` and rest `100` notes
- Amount withdrawn is greater than equal to `5000`

  - If `A%1000 == 0`, then the ATM spits 2 `500` notes and rest `1000` notes
  - Else if, `A%500 == 0`, the ATM spits 1 `500` note and rest `1000` notes
  - Else if `A%1000 < 500`, the ATM spits `floor(A/1000)` `1000` notes and rest `100` notes
  - Else if `A%1000 > 500`, the ATM spits `floor(A/1000)` `1000` notes, 1 `500` and rest `100` notes

For clarification, here is a complete table of notes withdrawn for all possible amounts up to `7000` (you can withdraw more, but the pattern does not change afterwards). The order is `<1000> <500> <100>`:

```
 100 => 0 0 1                  2500 => 2 0 5                   4800 => 4 1 3
 200 => 0 0 2                  2600 => 2 1 1                   4900 => 4 1 4
 300 => 0 0 3                  2700 => 2 1 2                   5000 => 4 2 0
 400 => 0 0 4                  2800 => 2 1 3                   5100 => 5 0 1
 500 => 0 0 5                  2900 => 2 1 4                   5200 => 5 0 2
 600 => 0 1 1                  3000 => 2 1 5                   5300 => 5 0 3
 700 => 0 1 2                  3100 => 3 0 1                   5400 => 5 0 4
 800 => 0 1 3                  3200 => 3 0 2                   5500 => 5 1 0
 900 => 0 1 4                  3300 => 3 0 3                   5600 => 5 1 1
1000 => 0 1 5                  3400 => 3 0 4                   5700 => 5 1 2
1100 => 1 0 1                  3500 => 3 0 5                   5800 => 5 1 3
1200 => 1 0 2                  3600 => 3 1 1                   5900 => 5 1 4
1300 => 1 0 3                  3700 => 3 1 2                   6000 => 5 2 0
1400 => 1 0 4                  3800 => 3 1 3                   6100 => 6 0 1
1500 => 1 0 5                  3900 => 3 1 4                   6200 => 6 0 2
1600 => 1 1 1                  4000 => 3 1 5                   6300 => 6 0 3
1700 => 1 1 2                  4100 => 4 0 1                   6400 => 6 0 4
1800 => 1 1 3                  4200 => 4 0 2                   6500 => 6 1 0
1900 => 1 1 4                  4300 => 4 0 3                   6600 => 6 1 1
2000 => 1 1 5                  4400 => 4 0 4                   6700 => 6 1 2
2100 => 2 0 1                  4500 => 4 0 5                   6800 => 6 1 3
2200 => 2 0 2                  4600 => 4 1 1                   6900 => 6 1 4
2300 => 2 0 3                  4700 => 4 1 2                   7000 => 6 2 0
2400 => 2 0 4
```

*List provided by Martin*

**The Catch**

Since the credit limit in your credit card is just enough, you need to make sure that the **total amount withdrawn across the withdrawals is the minimum possible** for the given input/requirement of notes.

**Input**

Input can be in any favorable format for three numbers corresponding to the number of notes required of value `1000`, `500` and `100`. Not necessarily in that order.

**Output**

Output is the amount to be withdrawn in each transaction separated by a new line.

**Examples**

Input (format `<1000> <500> <100>`):

```
3 4 1
```

Output:

```
600
600
600
3600
```

few more:

```
7 2 5
5000
3500

1 2 3
600
1700

21 14 2
600
600
600
1600
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
```

**Assumptions**

- You may assume that the ATM has infinite number of notes of each amount.
- You may also assume that you can make any number of transactions.
- Furthermore, the solution to some input values might not be unique, so you can output any 1 of the solution which fulfills the minimum amount possible and minimum notes required conditions.

As usual, you may write a full program reading input via STDIN/ARGV and printing output to STDOUT or a function taking input via arguments and returns either a list of integer corresponding to the amounts or a string with amounts separated by a new line.

This is code-golf so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: @nutki indeed . Edited.

Comment: Are there any speed restrictions? Should the last test case `21 14 2` finish in a reasonable time?

Comment: @Jakube In a reasonable time - yes (say less than 5-6 hours). But as such, no limit as this is code-golf.

Comment: So, if I withdraw 0, it will give me five 100 notes?

Comment: @AJMansfield of course not. You cannot withdraw 0 amount

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## JavaScript, <s>184</s> 148

```js
function g(a,b,c){x=[];while(a>0||b>0||c>0){i=b<3||a<4?a:4;a-=i;if(i>3&&b>1){b-=2;i++}else{i+=(c--<b&&i>4?0:.1)+(b-->0?.5:0)}x.push(i*1e3)}return x}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vuyv4r0p/2/

returns a list of integers corresponding to the withdrawal amounts

Comment: Try `g(5,1,1)`. One better solution: `5600`.

Comment: should be fixed now

Comment: `g(5,1,0)`, solution: `5500`.

Comment: that should now also be fixed ^^ thanks for pointing that out, i must be too sleepy

Comment: `g(5,2,0)`, solution: `6000`.

Comment: fixed, also shortened code by quite some bytes

Comment: You can save a few bytes by saying x.p=x.push

Comment: actually, it would be 2 bytes longer... x.p=x.push; is 11 bytes, bytes saved would be 3*3 = 9 bytes

Comment: Pretty sure `[2,1,4]` should give `[2900]`, right? Also with ES6 you can golf this to [131 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY3BqsIwEEX3fkhJzCTMNPEpoUk/RFwkxcK4EPGJdNF/rymPB6mbgXPuZe4tvdPv8OTHS79PyzIGkSDDAAxTOF9kiCniPOf1DBH7USQdOOTOznPqXJ@8A8HRNk2O1IusQwuslPSsghi07nLTcHQ9ekNSlVyXJ@bgUco9qr@hszFmAt7T1V6kn5bHk@8vMQqCFqyUu3@24IAqPsJhwy0BOWgrU/JNY2Ws@Kcs4GYB4VgxYRF1AYG@xaq@JsqL5QM "JavaScript (V8) – Try It Online")

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms: `[2900]`, `[2800,100]`, `[2700,100,100]` and `[2600,100,100,100]` are all valid solutions for the input `[2,1,4]`. Note how there is no requirement for minimizing the number of transactions, only the sum total. // Nice solution, sadly ES6 hadn't yet been around when I wrote this answer.

Comment: @hoffmale Oh, I didn't notice that was allowed, sorry :p. I think some of the changes in the ES6 one might have been possible in 2015, but this is a really impressive answer either way.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5: <strike>223</strike>

### Edit

This solution was done with a wrong assumption that 7K is the ATM limit. This actually made the task more interesting as it required dynamic programming (the move pattern was quite regular, but hard-coding it would be likely longer than calculating live as I did). With any amount possible the move pattern is so regular that it is trivial to hard-code it. I don't know if the solution by @hoffmale is now correct, but it will be among these lines. So sadly it will be another task where first somebody comes with a solution and then it gets ported to a golfing language for a win.

A bit slower than the original solution (but still sub-second for parameters below 100).

```
#!perl -pa
$c{0,0}=$f=($a,$b,$c)=@F;for$i(0..$b){for$j(0..$a){
/.(?=.$)/>($n=$c{$i-$`,$j-$'})||${$r=\$c{$i,$j}}<($x=$n+$&)&&$$r
or$f=$$r="$x $n".($'.$&+5*$`)."00
"for 204..206,105,106,11..15,110..114}}$_=$f."100
"x($c-$f+3);s/.*\b3//
```

Faster 259 solution.

```
#!perl -pa
$c{0,0}=($a,$b,$c)=@F;for$i(0..$b){for$j(0..$a){
/\B./<($%=$c{$i-$&,$j-$'}+$`)&&(!${$r=\$c{$i,$j}}||$$r>$%)and$d{$i,$j}=$_,$$r=$%for
qw/024 025 026 015 016/,101..105,110..114}}
$d{$b,$a}=~/\B./,$c-=$`,$b-=$&,$a-=$',print$'.$`+5*$&,"00
"while$a+$b;$_="100
"x$c
```

Uses STDIN:

```
$perl atm.pl <<<"21 14 2"
5000
5000
5000
5000
5000
600
600
600
1600
```

Comment: Try `10 0 0`. Better solution: `10100`.

Comment: @user23013 oops, I misunderstood the question. I assumed 7k is the maximum amount :( I hope I will be able to fix it.